# H1 text with a span size issue

Tags: css, html

I only know the basics of html and css.
 I'm trying to get my H1 with a span inside to display smaller than the h1 size

```
<h1>title<br><span>title 2</span><h1>
```

and then css

```
h1 {
font-size: font-size: 4.4em;
}

span {
display: block;
font-size : 1.4em;
}
```

but it still comes up the same size as the h1 please help!

Comment: By size do you mean font-size? Or width of the element?

Comment: Ditto in IE and FF. It doesn't come in the same size, experiment with changing sizes and u will see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `span` is inside `h1`, it will inherit the `font-size`.

`font-size` of `span` will be 4.4em if you dont give any `font-size` explicitly.

You want `font-size` of `span` smaller, means `font-size` should be less than 1em. 1em means same font-size as of parent's.

In your example it is 1.4em means 1.4 times of 4.4em.
Try:

```
span {
    display: block;
    font-size : 0.7em;
}
```

[**Fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/MEHkN/)

Comment: Huh, what? The span has a different `font-size` in the question it's at `1.4em` instead of `4.4em`.

Comment: +1 Exactly. To make a span in a `h1` have a smaller font size than the `h1` itself, you will need to specify something less than `1em`. At `1.4em`, it would be even larger than the rest of the `h1`.

Answer (score 2):

'em' is a relative unit for font-size and 'px' is a fixed value. So when you set the font-size as 4.4em for H1, it multiplies the default font-size of browser with 4.4 and displays the text  in that size. Your span is inside the H1. So essentially, your font size for the text in SPAN would be **(default font-size * 4.4) * 1.4**

Since the value is being multiplied by 1.4, you are not noticing the difference, but it is being applied. Try using a different value for SPAN font-size, like 2em and you will notice the difference.

And yes, as others pointed out, please correct the CSS syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Try this you entering wrong value to the css property

```
h1 {
font-size:4.4em;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have "font-size: font-size: " at your h1. Remove one:

```
h1 {
  font-size: 4.4em;
}

span {
  display: block;
  font-size : 1.4em;
}
```

Comment: @user2878889 You mean the HTML you posted here is not what you have on your site? Please don't do that, it will lead us off on wild goose chases.

Answer (score 1):

The “em” is a scalable unit that is used in web document media. An em is equal to the current font-size, for instance, if the font-size of the document is 12pt, 1em is equal to 12pt. Ems are scalable in nature, so 2em would equal 24pt, .5em would equal 6pt, etc.
Means In your case, you set font-siz for span 1.4em, it's mean your font size:

```
Actual Font Size of Inner Element (span) is :-  (font-size of the document) * (font-size of Parent Container h1 ) * (font-size of inner element span)
```

[Read this document](http://kyleschaeffer.com/development/css-font-size-em-vs-px-vs-pt-vs/)

```
Try to set PX value  - http://jsfiddle.net/c7LG5/
```